# Using apache2 to access multiple different internal servers using one public ip

Tags: networking, apache-http-server

I am a novice/hobbyist at server/networking stuff, so forgive me if I miss something obvious

My primary goal is to configure apache2 so that I can access multiple different self hosted servers under 1 residential ip address, without needing to use different ports for each server [eg. accessing Nextcloud, Matrix Element, and maybe a DAppNode for Ethereum if I can get that to work]. I can only forward a port to one ip each, so I figure, if I forward port 80 to an apache server that then redirects traffic based on domain name, I can access each site under one public ip.

So I got to testing this idea using a free tier of Amazon's EC2 service. I set up one apache (2.4.52) server, and one Matrix server [which runs under a docker (20.10.22, build 3a2c30b) container] (both running Ubuntu Server 22.04). I saw what "ProxyPass" was supposed to do, so figured that was my solution. This is my config to redirect traffic to the Matrix container

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test1.example.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://172.18.0.3:80
        ProxyPassReverse / http://172.18.0.3:80
</VirtualHost>
```

And yet going to test1.example.com [not actual url] gives me a "service unavailable" error, but the page loads fine while going to matrix.example.com [which is directed at the matrix server's public ip]. I'm probably doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what, or how to do it right

Also, I figured that I'd be able to have apache distinguish between the different subdomains if I put different subdomains as the server names, but I have no idea how that's how it works

Update: after some trial and error, i've come to realize that the problem isn't apache's reverse proxy [which works fine/as expected for index.html sites], it's specifically the matrix install i'm working with. it has too many moving parts that i'm not familiar with enough to be able to get it functioning properly. this seems to be a project for the future

Comment: Does this help:  [How to configure Apache as a reverse proxy](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-configure-Apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-example)

Comment: not really... i'm beginning to think that my problem is that i'm not properly forwarding the traffic to the docker container, but idk how to do it properly

Comment: ok... after spinning up another simple apache server, yes... my problem is indeed the docker container. the apachy proxy server reaches the new server via internal ip no problem. so... gotta figure out how to wrangle docker servers ig
...
I'm too inexperienced for this lmao